# How to convert a JSON array into an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsstring, nsarray

I've been having trouble finding out how to convert a JSON array into an NSArray.

I have a php script that creates an array that is converted into JSON which is then sent and stored into an NSString that looks like:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

My problem is that I need to make that into an NSArray of ints. How would one do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your app process JSON or a string?

Comment: There is no such thing as an NSArray of ints. NSArrays, NSDictionarys and NSSets may only contain ObjC-style objects, so what you would get using any of the JSON-Frameworks out there (i prefer JSONKit) will be an NSArray of NSNumbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I wanted to quickly break that into an array I would do it like this:

```
NSString * jstring = @"[1,2,3,4]";  //your json string

jstring = [jstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];
jstring = [jstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];

NSArray * intArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];



//you could create your int from the array like this
int x = [[intArray objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
```

Comment: yea ... no, he would not have an int-array, he would have an array with NSStrings.

Comment: yeah sorry, you would have to pull the strings as intValue

Comment: Thanks! This worked great.  But how could I pull the strings as intValues?

Answer (score 6):

You should look at the documentation of the [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

You can hand it the `NSData` received from a remote call that is a string in JSON format and receive the array or dictionary it contains.

```
NSObject *o =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                               error:&error];

// other useful "options":
// 0 
// NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
// NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
```

you should then check that `o` is of the type you expect for sanity purposes

Comment: This should be the way people go with JSON in iOS as more people install iOS5 on their devices.

Answer (score 0):

Import the SBJson in your project (drag and drop it)

```
#import "SBJson.h"
```

Then where you receive the JSON response from the php file

```
NSArray *array = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Comment: This works for decoding the JSON in the php but when I send it to the NSString all that appears is
    Array

Also, I was thinking I would have to edit my .m file in the iOS app, not the php.

Comment: aha. My bad. There is a great json library in Objective-c: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/