# Converting PHP JSON to NSArray

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I have a problem getting the values of PHP JSON into an NSArray.

These are the values I get from my JSON: `'1451'`, `'1450'`, `'1449'`.

How can I convert this into an NSArray?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, before you post a question here, please read the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for tips on posting.

Answer (score 1):

try `NSJSONSerialization` and assign it to a variable of type `id` and you could cast it like using `(NSArray)` or you could directly assign it to variable of type `NSArray` from `NSJsonserialization`

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
NSString * jstring = @"[1451,1450,1449]";  //your json string

jstring = [jstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];
jstring = [jstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];

NSArray * intArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];    
//you could create your int from the array like this
int x = [[intArray objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104840/3853188)

**Method 2**

```
NSObject *o =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                               error:&error];

NSArrary *arr=(NSArray*)o;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104935/3853188)